# strtotime() for a date that isn't in a standard form

Tags: php

I have a string in php that is a date but is formatted: `mddyy`
The `strtotime()` function does not understand this. I know I could split it into an array and move stuff around as needed to get where I need but is there something that would be better? What is a good way to convert this to a php date?

The format my dates are in are variable length(could be 5 digits, could be 6) depending on the month.

```
12511 = January 25 2011
110511 = November 5 2011
```

Comment: @Mike: Give us an example of the date. Is it like `122511` (for `December 25, 2011`)?

Comment: The month is 1 digit for 1 digit months and then 2 digits for 2 digit months. If that is what you are referring to?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, that's what I am referring to.

Comment: Even `createFromFormat` has issues with a date like this. It reports `12511` as `2002-01-20`. The only way to solve this in as less code as possible is to use @neokio's solution. I can't think of anything else, which would work out well for you.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the createfromformat function. I did not know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get date_create_from_format to work by padding a 0 on the left.

```
date_create_from_format("mjy", str_pad($date, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

Comment: This is clearly the best and cleanest solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

use substr to split it out...

```
$date='72811';
if (strlen($date)==5) {
    // 5 digit dates
    $unixtime = mktime(0,0,0, substr(0,1,$date), substr(1,2,$date), substr(3,2,$date));
} else {
    // 6 digit dates
    $unixtime = mktime(0,0,0, substr(0,2,$date), substr(2,2,$date), substr(4,2,$date));
}
```

Comment: Oh dear, I wrote the idea at the same time you wrote updated code ;d